# how to implement a linear layout to show two text view one in right and one in left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to know how to implement a layout like this:

---

|  -----------                       ----------- |
|  |txtStatus|                       |txtDate  | |
|  -----------                       ----------- |
|-------------------------------------------------
this point is that `txtStatus` should be in the very right of screen and `txtDate` should be in very left of `LinearLayout`.

I dont want to set any margin and specific size here.

My current xml layout is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shareRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

Comment: u can use relative layout and set  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to second one  and  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  to first

Comment: @steevoo solution is also useful

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use Relative layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/txtDate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="right"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="left"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you feel you are comfort with LinearLayout, you can use the following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shareRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Hai how are you" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Hai there" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Solution

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="20" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="5"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="Date : "
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="5"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="Status : "
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `RelativeLayout` inside `LinearLayout`. And put `TextViews` inside Relative with `layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `layout_alignParentRight="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead : With `layout_alignParentLeft` and `layout_alignParentRight` as true for respective textViews

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/shareRow"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"/>  

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

The middle view will acquire the space remaining between the left and right views but nothing will be visible

Answer (score 0):

Try This it might be helpful to you...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/shareRow"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="50" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Date"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Status"/>
            </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weight parameter does requires android:layout_width

Comment: @SuhailMehta you need to use `android:layout_width` even if you use weight parameter, Because weight and layout:width were two different things. for more info about weight i suggest you to read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight)